# access from docker stack mode to local network host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, stack

I need make ftp connection to `192.168...` network host (local network), and connection to mongo container.

Docker in swarm mode blocks `network_mode:host` (and I can't see remote ftp host inside container)

Docker stack has docs about `--publish mode=host,target=80,published=8080`, but I can't find out how write it in docker-compose file.

My `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'

services:

  node:
    image: tgbot-test_node_1
    build:
      context: ..
    env_file: .env.test
    network_mode: host
    links:
      - mongo # works
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    deploy:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    network_mode: "bridge"
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8080:80 # not works, only expose 27017/tcp
#      not works
#      - mode: host
#        target: 27019
#        published: 27017
    env_file:
      - .env.test
    volumes:
    - db:/data/db
    deploy:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.75'

volumes:
  db:
```

I need swarm mode for limiting resourses.

### How can I access ftp host?

- Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
- docker-compose version 1.26.2, build eefe0d31

**UPD**
with Joel Magnuson answer I got `PORTS: 27017/tcp` of mongo container. It not forward ports with `stack deploy`, any - would it be "80:80" or "27017"

I set

```
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
```

and got

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
ab58c781fdb9        mongo:latest               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        27017/tcp           tgbot-test_mongo.1.3i7yps3saqo3nk4xxyk0eka7h
43c0e3cfe960        tgbot-test_node_1:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds                            tgbot-test_node.1.v23cufsrr683gdg2bicgf80q2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a configuration issue. You mentioned "FTP host" but you didn't mention about running an FTP server. Hopefully the below helps with your mongo database.

`mongodb` will always run on port `27017` inside the container by default unless configured, so you must mount the container's port of `27017` to the host, not port `80`.

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  node:
    image: tgbot-test_node_1
    env_file: .env.test       # configure with mongodb://mongo:27017/<db name>
    networks:
      - tgbot-test    

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017   # only needed if you want to access it outside of the stack
                      # otherwise it's always visible within the stack network as 'mongo'
    volumes:
      - /home/$USER/db:/data/db    # can mount to host instead
    networks:
      - tgbot-test

networks:
  tgbot-test:
    driver: overlay     #suggest overlay network
    
#volumes:
#  db:     # this is not persistent by itself - can mount to host
```

You could also create an external volume.
`docker volume create --name tgbot-db`

```yaml
...
volumes:
  tgbot-db:
    external: true
```

You should be able to connect to the mongodb instance from the host or remote with `mongodb://192.160.X.X:27017/<db name>` or inside a container in the same stack using `docker swarm`'s DNS name of `mongo`(service name) with `mongodb://mongo:27017/<db name>`.

Comment: thanks. My fault. 192.168... already pinged from node container. I can deal with overlay networks. But why `docker ps` not show forwarder ports? Throught portainer I see "27018:27017" on mongo service, but `docker ps` not show this.

Comment: The `docker ps` ports I think are an artifact of the Dockerfile exposing the ports even though in your case `27017` shouldn't be accessible outside the stack network. `docker service ls` or `docker stack services <stack name>` should show you the service port binding `27018:27017` as portainer displays.